# Clojure: Finding the minimum value within vectors of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence with a structure like this:

```
(def date-sequence [[20101121 10] [20101120 9] [20101119 8] [20101118 7]])
```

This looks to like a nested vector to me, but I'm unsure what to name it. Within each "nested vector" are two elements, a date element and value element: `[20101121 10]`. Let's call the date element `20101121 x`, and the value element `10 y`.

I want to learn how to find the date(x) and value(y) that correspond to the minimum value(y) across the entire date-sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
user=> (apply min-key second date-sequence)
[20101118 7]
```

You can then use `first` and `second` to get the date and value.